# Acumatica REST API not setting custom field value

Tags: acumatica

Using Acumatica 17.210.0034 and API endpoint 17.200.001, I'm doing a PUT including custom fields, but the custom field values are not being set in the db. Any help would be appreciated.  The same thing happens with an insert and an update. The data is added, but the custom field values are not set.

PUT url:

```
http://localhost/acuroyalbay172100034/entity/Default/17.200.001/StockItem?%24custom=InventoryItemExt.UsrSquareFTG%2cInventoryItemExt.UsrDispPerPallet%2cInventoryItemExtension.UsrItemClassCD%2cInventoryItemAMExtension.AMReplenishmentSource%2cInventoryItemAMExtension.AMLotSize%2cInventoryItemAMExtension.AMMaxOrdQty%2cInventoryItemAMExtension.AMMinOrdQty%2cInventoryItemAMExtension.AMLowLevel%2cInventoryItemAMExtension.AMMRPItem%2cInventoryItemAMExtension.AMMFGLeadTime%2cInventoryItemAMExtension.AMGroupWindow%2cInventoryItemAMExtension.AMConfigurationID%2cInventoryItemAMExtension.AMReplenishmentSourceOverride%2cInventoryItemAMExtension.AMSafetyStockOverride%2cInventoryItemAMExtension.AMSafetyStock%2cInventoryItemAMExtension.AMMinQtyOverride%2cInventoryItemAMExtension.AMMinQty%2cInventoryItemAMExtension.AMQtyRoundUp
```

Request Body:

```
{
  "AverageCost": {
    "value": 0.0
  },
  "BaseUOM": {
    "value": "EA"
  },
  "COGSAccount": {
    "value": "50000"
  },
  "COGSSubaccount": {
    "value": "CON000"
  },
  "CurrentStdCost": {
    "value": 0.0
  },
  "DefaultIssueLocationID": {
    "value": "R1S1"
  },
  "DefaultPrice": {
    "value": 0.0
  },
  "DefaultReceiptLocationID": {
    "value": "RECEIVING"
  },
  "DefaultWarehouseID": {
    "value": "WHOLESALE"
  },
  "Description": {
    "value": "tonyitem153"
  },
  "DimensionVolume": {
    "value": 0.0
  },
  "DimensionWeight": {
    "value": 0.0
  },
  "InventoryAccount": {
    "value": "12100"
  },
  "InventoryID": {
    "value": "RGTONYIT153"
  },
  "InventorySubaccount": {
    "value": "CON000"
  },
  "IsAKit": {
    "value": false
  },
  "ItemClass": {
    "value": "CONSUMER  200FITNESS"
  },
  "ItemStatus": {
    "value": "Active"
  },
  "ItemType": {
    "value": "Finished Good"
  },
  "LandedCostVarianceAccount": {
    "value": "52400"
  },
  "LandedCostVarianceSubaccount": {
    "value": "CON000"
  },
  "LastCost": {
    "value": 0.0
  },
  "LastModified": {
    "value": "2018-09-11T12:36:15.483-04:00"
  },
  "LastStdCost": {
    "value": 0.0
  },
  "LotSerialClass": {
    "value": "NOTTRACKED"
  },
  "Markup": {
    "value": 0.0
  },
  "MaxCost": {
    "value": 0.0
  },
  "MinCost": {
    "value": 0.0
  },
  "MinMarkup": {
    "value": 0.0
  },
  "MSRP": {
    "value": 0.0
  },
  "PackagingOption": {
    "value": "Manual"
  },
  "PackSeparately": {
    "value": false
  },
  "PendingStdCost": {
    "value": 0.0
  },
  "POAccrualAccount": {
    "value": "20100"
  },
  "POAccrualSubaccount": {
    "value": "CON000"
  },
  "PostingClass": {
    "value": "CON"
  },
  "PurchasePriceVarianceAccount": {
    "value": "52300"
  },
  "PurchasePriceVarianceSubaccount": {
    "value": "CON000"
  },
  "PurchaseUOM": {
    "value": "EA"
  },
  "ReasonCodeSubaccount": {
    "value": "CON000"
  },
  "SalesAccount": {
    "value": "40000"
  },
  "SalesSubaccount": {
    "value": "CON000"
  },
  "SalesUOM": {
    "value": "EA"
  },
  "StandardCostRevaluationAccount": {
    "value": "52110"
  },
  "StandardCostRevaluationSubaccount": {
    "value": "CON000"
  },
  "StandardCostVarianceAccount": {
    "value": "52100"
  },
  "StandardCostVarianceSubaccount": {
    "value": "CON000"
  },
  "SubjectToCommission": {
    "value": false
  },
  "TaxCategory": {
    "value": "TAXABLE"
  },
  "ValuationMethod": {
    "value": "Average"
  },
  "custom": {
    "InventoryItemExt": {
      "UsrSquareFTG": {
        "type": "CustomDecimalField",
        "value": 5.0
      },
      "UsrDispPerPallet": {
        "type": "CustomIntField",
        "value": 6
      }
    },
    "InventoryItemExtension": {
      "UsrItemClassCD": {
        "type": "CustomStringField",
        "value": "CONSUMER  200FITNESS"
      }
    },
    "InventoryItemAMExtension": {
      "AMReplenishmentSource": {
        "type": "CustomStringField",
        "value": "Purchase"
      },
      "AMLotSize": {
        "type": "CustomDecimalField",
        "value": 0.0
      },
      "AMMaxOrdQty": {
        "type": "CustomDecimalField",
        "value": 0.0
      },
      "AMMinOrdQty": {
        "type": "CustomDecimalField",
        "value": 0.0
      },
      "AMLowLevel": {
        "type": "CustomIntField",
        "value": 0
      },
      "AMMRPItem": {
        "type": "CustomBooleanField",
        "value": true
      },
      "AMMFGLeadTime": {
        "type": "CustomIntField",
        "value": 0
      },
      "AMGroupWindow": {
        "type": "CustomIntField",
        "value": 0
      },
      "AMConfigurationID": {
        "type": "CustomStringField"
      },
      "AMReplenishmentSourceOverride": {
        "type": "CustomBooleanField",
        "value": false
      },
      "AMSafetyStockOverride": {
        "type": "CustomBooleanField",
        "value": false
      },
      "AMSafetyStock": {
        "type": "CustomDecimalField",
        "value": 0.0
      },
      "AMMinQtyOverride": {
        "type": "CustomBooleanField",
        "value": false
      },
      "AMMinQty": {
        "type": "CustomDecimalField",
        "value": 0.0
      },
      "AMQtyRoundUp": {
        "type": "CustomBooleanField",
        "value": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "id": "2299727f-c471-46de-a8ac-9dcfe1a2a09f",
    "rowNumber": 1,
    "note": null,
    "ABCCode": {},
    "AutoIncrementalValue": {},
    "AverageCost": {
        "value": 0
    },
    "BaseUOM": {
        "value": "EA"
    },
    "COGSAccount": {
        "value": "50000"
    },
    "COGSSubaccount": {
        "value": "CON000"
    },
    "Content": {},
    "CurrentStdCost": {
        "value": 0
    },
    "DefaultIssueLocationID": {
        "value": "R1S1"
    },
    "DefaultPrice": {
        "value": 0
    },
    "DefaultReceiptLocationID": {
        "value": "RECEIVING"
    },
    "DefaultWarehouseID": {
        "value": "WHOLESALE"
    },
    "DeferralAccount": {},
    "DeferralSubaccount": {},
    "Description": {
        "value": "tonyitem153"
    },
    "DimensionVolume": {
        "value": 0
    },
    "DimensionWeight": {
        "value": 0
    },
    "DiscountAccount": {},
    "DiscountSubaccount": {},
    "ImageUrl": {},
    "InventoryAccount": {
        "value": "12100"
    },
    "InventoryID": {
        "value": "RGTONYIT153"
    },
    "InventorySubaccount": {
        "value": "CON000"
    },
    "IsAKit": {
        "value": false
    },
    "ItemClass": {
        "value": "CONSUMER  200FITNESS"
    },
    "ItemStatus": {
        "value": "Active"
    },
    "ItemType": {
        "value": "Finished Good"
    },
    "LandedCostVarianceAccount": {
        "value": "52400"
    },
    "LandedCostVarianceSubaccount": {
        "value": "CON000"
    },
    "LastCost": {
        "value": 0
    },
    "LastModified": {
        "value": "2018-09-11T12:56:47.843-04:00"
    },
    "LastStdCost": {
        "value": 0
    },
    "LotSerialClass": {
        "value": "NOTTRACKED"
    },
    "Markup": {
        "value": 0
    },
    "MaxCost": {
        "value": 0
    },
    "MinCost": {
        "value": 0
    },
    "MinMarkup": {
        "value": 0
    },
    "MSRP": {
        "value": 0
    },
    "PackagingOption": {
        "value": "Manual"
    },
    "PackSeparately": {
        "value": false
    },
    "PendingStdCost": {
        "value": 0
    },
    "POAccrualAccount": {
        "value": "20100"
    },
    "POAccrualSubaccount": {
        "value": "CON000"
    },
    "PostingClass": {
        "value": "CON"
    },
    "PriceClass": {},
    "PriceManager": {},
    "PriceWorkgroup": {},
    "ProductManager": {},
    "ProductWorkgroup": {},
    "PurchasePriceVarianceAccount": {
        "value": "52300"
    },
    "PurchasePriceVarianceSubaccount": {
        "value": "CON000"
    },
    "PurchaseUOM": {
        "value": "EA"
    },
    "ReasonCodeSubaccount": {
        "value": "CON000"
    },
    "SalesAccount": {
        "value": "40000"
    },
    "SalesSubaccount": {
        "value": "CON000"
    },
    "SalesUOM": {
        "value": "EA"
    },
    "StandardCostRevaluationAccount": {
        "value": "52110"
    },
    "StandardCostRevaluationSubaccount": {
        "value": "CON000"
    },
    "StandardCostVarianceAccount": {
        "value": "52100"
    },
    "StandardCostVarianceSubaccount": {
        "value": "CON000"
    },
    "SubjectToCommission": {
        "value": false
    },
    "TaxCategory": {
        "value": "TAXABLE"
    },
    "ValuationMethod": {
        "value": "Average"
    },
    "VolumeUOM": {},
    "WeightUOM": {},
    "custom": {
        "InventoryItemExt": {
            "UsrSquareFTG": {
                "type": "CustomDecimalField",
                "value": null
            },
            "UsrDispPerPallet": {
                "type": "CustomIntField",
                "value": null
            }
        },
        "InventoryItemExtension": {
            "UsrItemClassCD": {
                "type": "CustomStringField",
                "value": null
            }
        },
        "InventoryItemAMExtension": {
            "AMReplenishmentSource": {
                "type": "CustomStringField",
                "value": "Purchase"
            },
            "AMLotSize": {
                "type": "CustomDecimalField",
                "value": 0
            },
            "AMMaxOrdQty": {
                "type": "CustomDecimalField",
                "value": 0
            },
            "AMMinOrdQty": {
                "type": "CustomDecimalField",
                "value": 0
            },
            "AMLowLevel": {
                "type": "CustomIntField",
                "value": 0
            },
            "AMMRPItem": {
                "type": "CustomBooleanField",
                "value": true
            },
            "AMMFGLeadTime": {
                "type": "CustomIntField",
                "value": 0
            },
            "AMGroupWindow": {
                "type": "CustomIntField",
                "value": 0
            },
            "AMConfigurationID": {
                "type": "CustomStringField",
                "value": null
            },
            "AMReplenishmentSourceOverride": {
                "type": "CustomBooleanField",
                "value": false
            },
            "AMSafetyStockOverride": {
                "type": "CustomBooleanField",
                "value": false
            },
            "AMSafetyStock": {
                "type": "CustomDecimalField",
                "value": 0
            },
            "AMMinQtyOverride": {
                "type": "CustomBooleanField",
                "value": false
            },
            "AMMinQty": {
                "type": "CustomDecimalField",
                "value": 0
            },
            "AMQtyRoundUp": {
                "type": "CustomBooleanField",
                "value": false
            }
        }
    },
    "files": []
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the answer is that you have to extend an endpoint in order to update data with a PUT.  Using the GET data structure which includes custom fields as a collection doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Normally the custom key word is part of the Parameter for retrieving record as shown in this help article.

- https://help.acumatica.com/(W(4))/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=c5e2f36a-0971-4b33-b127-3c3fe14106ff

If you want to set values to these field then you will need to add the field to the endpoint first.

Here are some link on how to create an extended endpoint:

Custom Endpoints and Endpoint Extensions

- https://help.acumatica.com/(W(4))/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=c920d9fc-8e81-4f4e-9250-81c6fb979517

Custom Fields

- https://help.acumatica.com/(W(4))/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=bd0d8a36-b00b-44c8-bdcd-b2b4e4c86fd0

Comment: It sounds like you have to create or extend endpoints to get any custom fields to insert or update. That's unfortunate. If they're specified in the request, I would think it would handle it, but I guess not.  Is there any way to do this programmatically, or do I have to set up an endpoint within the UI and attach it to a package?  What if I want to make the code dynamic to work with any custom fields?  Do I always have to specify manually through the UI?

Comment: I started extending the endpoint to get custom fields, but can I only select custom fields that are on a screen?  Does the API only include screen-based custom fields?  If not, how do I add a custom field that's not displayed on a screen?

Comment: Also, when I add an endpoint to a custom package, then deploy the package on another instance, the endpoint loses all its custom fields which I added.  Do I have to configure all the fields for an extended endpoint manually on each instance?

Comment: You can put custom fields, but you wrongly form your json.

Comment: Kirill, the json came from a GET, so I don't understand how it could be wrong.  More info please?

Answer (score 0):

The problem of your request body is here:

```
"custom": {
  "InventoryItemExt": {
    "UsrSquareFTG": {
      "type": "CustomDecimalField",
      "value": 5.0
    },
    "UsrDispPerPallet": {
      "type": "CustomIntField",
      "value": 6
    }
  },
 ...
 }
```

Custom fields collection should have another format and key.

To get correct json schema of entity with its custom fields you can use get request to address http://localhost/acuroyalbay172100034/entity/Default/17.200.001/StockItem/$adHocSchema

it will returns you json that includes custom fields. You can use it as template for your request bodies.
see also [Help](https://help.acumatica.com/(W(4))/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=64daacf1-75c4-4bfa-b57b-36222020e7c9)

Comment: I understand that, but this is a PUT, not a GET, and I'm already including custom fields, but the API endpoint doesn't apparently do anything with them unless I extend it.

Comment: You place them in wrong format, in wrong collection. Please get schema and fill it, then put. Of cause if you want to achieve your goal.

Comment: I don't understand how it could be the wrong format.  This is the format a GET (by key) responded with.  In any case, are you saying that I can do a PUT with a field that's not in the data contract?  Or are you saying I still have to extend it?  As I said below, I've extended the endpoint now because I couldn't find any other way to do it.

Comment: I understand you're saying to fill an empty schema, but that's very tedious.  I'm just doing a GET by key with values filled in, then using that.  It sounds like I need to add the custom fields myself using this technique, though.  Will the default endpoint allow me to send custom fields, though, or am I required to extend it?